# MySQL query for search filter from multiple tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have multiple tables and i have a search ASP.NET page with a GridView for the results.
The GridView must contain Name, School, State, Country
I have multiple tables that only contains the data:

**index_States**

```
indexID| State
----------------
 1     | state1
 2     | state2
 3     | state3
```

**index_Contries**

```
indexID| Country
----------------
 1     | country1
 2     | country2
 3     | country3
```

**index_Schools**

```
indexID| School
----------------
 1     | school1
 2     | school2
 3     | school3
```

Then i have the tables that contains the indexID as reference
**General_Info**

```
idKey | Name 
--------------
 1    | John
 2    | McClane
 3    | Jr.
```

**Academic_XP**

```
id | idSchool | idState | idCountry | idKey
--------------------------------------------
 1 |    1     |   3     |    20     |  2
 2 |    1     |   5     |    146    |  3
 3 |    2     |   1     |    65     |  9
```

And THEN I have the table that contains UserType as only certain type of user will be searched
**Users**

```
id | UserType | idKey
-----------------------
 1 |    1     |   1
 2 |    3     |   2
 3 |    3     |   3
 4 |    1     |   4
```

I've already tried multiple queries but none seem to be working.
Last query that seem to be working was with ***INNER JOIN***

```
SELECT Name, State
FROM General_Info A, Academic_XP B
INNER JOIN index_States D ON B.idState = D.indexID
GROUP BY A.id;
```

but it doesn't work as soon as I add a second ***INNER JOIN*** or a ***WHERE*** clause.

```
SELECT Name, State
FROM General_Info A, Academic_XP B, Users
INNER JOIN index_States D ON B.idState = D.indexID
INNER JOIN index_School E ON B.idSchool = E.indexID
GROUP BY A.id
WHERE Users.UserType = 3;
```

I don't know how can I do that.
So i guess the question is

**How can I made a query that returns from all those tables something like this?**

```
Name    | State  | School  | Country
---------------------------------------
McClane | state3 | school1 | country20 
Jr.     | state1 | school5 | country146
```

Note that *McClane* and *Jr.* are both UserType 3.
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A.idState' in 'on clause'

Comment: I'm confused how your query maps to your sample tables. But if I'm reading this right, there is no `idState` in General_Info, so of course that would fail... Don't you want `idKey`?

Comment: it's true, that was my fault in typing. INNER JOIN index_States D ON B.idState = D.indexID is the correct one and I already edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are producing a `cartesian product` between tables without joins.  I think this is what you're looking for using additional `JOINs`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       G.Name,
       S.State,
       C.Country,
       SC.School
FROM Academic_XP A
    JOIN Users U ON A.idKey = U.idKey
    JOIN General_Info G ON A.id = G.idKey
    JOIN Index_States S ON A.idState = S.indexID
    JOIN Index_Contries C ON A.idCountry = C.indexID
    JOIN Index_Schools SC ON A.idSchool = SC.indexID
WHERE U.UserType = 3
```

If some tables don't have matching keys, you'll need to use an `OUTER JOIN`.

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)